# I failed to get the desired by ORM

Tags: django

**Django==1.11.5**

I failed to get by ORM what I get by raw SQL select.

**I need tag.id and tag's text.**

Could you help me understand the situation:

1. Is it possible to use ORM to get the desired result?
2. Below is the code that works ok and ORM selection which is a complete fail. Could you tell me whether the code is acceptable or not.

**tags.models**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                           blank=True,
                           null=False,
                           default="",
                           unique=True,
                           verbose_name=_('tag'))
```

**frametags.models**

```
class FrameTag(models.Model):
    frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              verbose_name=_("frame"))

    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            verbose_name=_("tag"))
```

**ORM (failing attempt)**

```
>>> f = Frame.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f.frametag_set.all()
<QuerySet [<FrameTag: Frame 1, tag sport>, <FrameTag: Frame 1, tag dancing>]>
```

**What I did:**

```
def custom_sql(frame_instance):

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select tags_tag.id, tags_tag.tag from frametags_frametag join tags_tag on (tags_tag.id=tag_id) where frame_id=%s", [frame_instance.id])

        rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return rows

def show_tags(frame_instance):
    rows = custom_sql(frame_instance)

    return {'object_list': rows }
```

Comment: What was your desired output?

Comment: I need tag.id and tag's text. I edit the initial question to show Tag model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values_list` query should solve your problem,

Try this,

```
f = Frame.objects.get(pk=1)
list(f.frametag_set.all().values_list('tag_id','tag__tag'))
```

This will return you a list of tuples containing `tag` `id` and `name`

Hope This Helps :-)